# PouchDB to make queries on CouchDB

Tags: ajax, couchdb, pouchdb

I develop an app with PhoneGap and JQM. I will also use PouchDB as database on device side coupled with CouchDB as database on server side.

I would like to know if it is possible to use PouchDB to send query to CouchDB. For example, I want to have a login mechanism. So I need to check the credentials on the server side. My first idea is to send an ajax request to a PHP file that will check the credentials in the CouchDB database.
I would do the same for the signup: send data to PHP through Ajax to create a new record in my server database.

However, as PouchDB and CouchDB are really close, maybe is it possible to don’t use an ajax query and a PHP file to do it. Maybe is it possible to send queries (read and write) to CouchDB from PouchDB.
Is it possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use PouchDb as a CouchDb Driver

```
var db = new PouchDB('https://myserver:5984/mdb');
// this gives you the PouchDB API but it will request data from the CouchDb Server
```

There is a pouchdb plugin that provides some authentication methods to the pouchdb api:

```
var db = new PouchDB('http://mysite:5984/mydb');
db.login('batman', 'brucewayne').then(function (batman) {
  console.log("I'm Batman.");
  return db.logout();
});
```

Here are the methods it mixes in:

- signup
- login
- logout
- getSession
- getUser

To prevent browser HTTP basic authentication modal dialogs of ye olde times, we have to be subtle in the way we use PouchDB. To prevent a rouge unauthenticated request to CouchDB (used to check whether the remote DB exists), pass skipSetup: true in Pouch's constructor options. Secondly, to authenticate the request against _session, add the HTTP basic authorization header to db.login()'s AJAX options.

```
var user = {
  name: 'admin',
  password: 'admin'
};

var pouchOpts = {
  skipSetup: true
};

var ajaxOpts = {
  ajax: {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Basic ' + window.btoa(user.name + ':' + user.password)
    }
  }
};

var db = new PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/test', pouchOpts);

db.login(user.name, user.password, ajaxOpts).then(function() {
  return db.allDocs();
}).then(function(docs) {
  console.log(docs);
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.error(error);
});
```